# Simple <button> alignment inside <form> using vertical-align

Tags: html, css

The [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) CSS property doesn't the desired effect, whether on the [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) or [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) tag.

Code:

```html
<form style="vertical-align: center;">
    <input type="button" value="trial" />
    <textarea cols="80" rows="17"></textarea>
</form>
```

[image: vertical-align doesn't show desired effect]

Comment: What is the desired effect?

Answer (score 1):

Are you attempting to position the "trial" button to the left and middle of the textarea? If so, try this:

```html
<form style="display: flex;">
        <input type="button" value="trial" style="align-self: center"/>
        <textarea cols="80" rows="17"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attribute **vertical-align** does not accept the value of **center**. You should use a value of **middle** instead.

Answer (score 0):

[`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) doesn't accept `center` as a value but rather `middle`, and it centers elements vertically.

`justify-*` like [`justify-self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self), [`justify-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-items), or [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) center elements horizontally (it accepts `center` as value not `middle`) so depending on the desired effect, you can center your elements.